# Resharper Inspect code analysis for set of projects not for whole solution

Tags: resharper

I am running following command to do the code analysis using Resharper command line tool. I am able to generate report for the whole solution.
i am not able to fine how i can do the same for a set of projects not for whole solution ?
How i can skip some of projects from the analysis

`c:\softwares\ReSharper.CommandLineTools>inspectcode.x86.exe /output=resharper-re
sults.xml C:\test\Test.sln /project="Test.Business"`

Comment: Does it work without the quotes round "Test.Business"? Does adding the `/no-swea` flag make a difference?

Comment: i would like to run the analysis for specific projects e.g project="Project.Business , Project.MVC" etc

Answer (score 1):

According to [JetBrain's announcement of the tool](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode), the `/project` flag:

> allows analyzing particular project(s) instead of the whole solution. After this parameter, you can type a project name or a wildcard that matches several projects within your solution

So I think you have several options:

1. analyze each project separately
2. name your projects so they can be run in groups with wildcards
3. create new dummy solutions containing the groups of projects you are interested in and run solution-wide analysis on those

It seems likely that JetBrains will add the syntax you want eventually; you might as well contact them to make the request.

Comment: yes i saw that but i am not able to run the same for multiple projects as you can see the same in my question example above i am using /project directive . can you give an example how i can use this for multiple project i have project name e.g Blog.Mvc,Blog.Business,Blog.Repository i don't want to run test for blog.mvc .

Comment: you can either *rename* your projects to make a wildcard match easy (hence the *name* in #2 above) or use something contrived that happens to match, such as `Blog.*s*` [assuming that works... I haven't tried it]